# Rewrite code from javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I have code in javascript:

```
if (imageData[imageCount].comments.data != null) 
{
 text = 'Comments Data:<br />';
 imageData[imageCount].comments.data.forEach(function(comment){
 text += comment.from.username + ': ' + comment.text + '<br />';
});
}
```

Which imageData[imageCount] refers to $data in PHP.

i've trying to rewrite self in PHP but it doesn't worked.

```
foreach ($contents->data as $data) { 
if ($data->comments->data != null) 
{
 foreach($data->comments->data as $comment)
 {
  $text = comment->from->username + ': ' + comment->text + '<br />';
 });
}
```

I'm sure to have problem with the code structure. It returns Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()`

**-- Edit --**

I've successed to convert the snippet to PHP. But i faced a new problem since i'm trying to create XML File from API (in this case Instagram API).
Look at productName and productPrice attribute from product section:

`http://pastebin.com/ubGGyp9b`

Value productName="Sushi Homemade " and productPrice="50.000 " is just for productID="002". But why the value also filled to next productID >= 002.

Is there mistake from this code:

```
<products>
<category categoryName="Instagram">
    <?php
```

foreach ($contents->data as $data) {

```
foreach($data->comments->data as $comment){
          if(preg_match('/#title/', $comment->text)){
          $komen = preg_replace('/#title/', '', $comment->text);
          break;
          } else { $komen = 'No Title'; }
}

foreach($data->comments->data as $comment){
          if(preg_match('/#price/', $comment->text)){
          $harga = preg_replace('/#price/', '', $comment->text);
          break;
          } else { $harga = '0'; }
}


          echo '<product productName="'. $komen .'" productID="' . $data->id . '" thumbPath="' . $data->images->thumbnail->url . '" productPrice="'. $harga .'">
        <details>
                    <![CDATA[
                    <img src="' . $data->images->low_resolution->url . '" width="100%"/>
        ' . $data->caption->text . '
                    ]]>
        </details>
</product>
```

Comment: `comment` is going to cause problems. `$comment`, perhaps? And of course, in PHP, `.` is the concatentation operator. You're doing a bunch of "string math" with `+`.

Comment: PHP doesn't use `+` for concatenation either.

Comment: Are `$contents->data` and `$data->comments->data` arrays?  You didn't indicate which foreach is causing the problem.

Comment: // Initialize class
 $instagram = new Instagram($accessToken);
 $instagram->setAccessToken($accessToken);
 $contents = $instagram->getUserMedia($userID,$settings['count']);

Comment: i have edited the question. Please look above

Answer (score 1):

You forgot an $ in the last line and some brackets were not correctly set. To concat strings in PHP use "." instead of "+"

```
foreach ($contents->data as $data) {
    if ($data->comments->data != null) {
        foreach ($data->comments->data as $comment) {
            $text = $comment->from->username . ': ' . $comment->text . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and make sure if the containing data are objects or arrays or strings :)